# Creaing php contact form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm new to php to I've tried to write my own php contact form to learn. Obviously having troubles now, here's my code:

```
<form action="mail-2.php" method="POST">
<p>Your Name (required)</p> <input type="text" name="name">
</br></br><p>Your Email (required)</p> <input type="text" name="email">
</br></br><p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
</br></br>
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

</br></br>
<input type="submit" name="saveForm" value="Send">
</form>
```

and php: mail-2.php

```
<?php
$to = "petermikhail96@gmail.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#4A148C;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

can anyone help me to get this working? It goes to the thank you page after I click send but the email does not go through.

Also I need to add an attachment to the form too but after several attempts I think I failed

Comment: Have you configured the smtp settings ? You trying in online or local ?

Comment: You need a MTA like postfix for the `mail()` function to work.